# How to preserve position after page reload using infinite scroll in Django

Tags: python, html, django, infinite-scroll

I have implemented infinite scroll for my data objects using jQuery and Waypoints. Works fine but I want to make it more convenient.

1. First of all I`m looking for a way to preserve position after page reload.
2. Also would be nice to add fixed pagination bar with a possibility to dislay your curent page dynamically while scrolling. I have add one, but how to dynamically display your position. Implies, I have 20 objects per page, when scrolling down for 20 next it should automatically switch current page for second one on pagination bar. And vice versa for scrolling up.
3. Another question is when choosing exact page at my current pagination menu it opens separate page with link 'http://127.0.0.1:8000/?page=2' for example, and displays objects only from 41th to 60th. I need it to open exact page but with possibility to scroll up and down for previous and next pages. Which way it`s possible to do this?

Here is my code below.

*models.py*

```
from django.core.validators import MinValueValidator, MaxValueValidator
from django.db import models


class Bancnote(models.Model):
    type = models.CharField(max_length=11)
    par = models.PositiveIntegerField()
    year_from = models.PositiveIntegerField()
    year_to = models.PositiveIntegerField()
    size = models.CharField(max_length=7)
    sign = models.CharField(max_length=20)
    desc = models.TextField(max_length=200)
    image = models.ImageField(upload_to='bons_images')

    def __str__(self):
        return str(self.par) + ' ' + self.type + ' ' + str(self.year_from) + '-' + str(self.year_to)
```

*views.py*

```
from django.core.paginator import Paginator, PageNotAnInteger, EmptyPage
from django.shortcuts import render, render_to_response
from django.template import RequestContext
from django.views import generic

from catalogue.models import Bancnote


def index(request):
    bons_list = Bancnote.objects.all().order_by('par')
    page = request.GET.get('page', 1)
    paginator = Paginator(bons_list, 20)
    try:
        bons = paginator.page(page)
    except PageNotAnInteger:
        bons = paginator.page(1)
    except EmptyPage:
        bons = paginator.page(paginator.num_pages)
    return render(request, 'catalogue/index.html', {'bons': bons})


def image(request):
    bons = Bancnote()
    variables = RequestContext(request, {
        'bons': bons
    })
    return render_to_response('catalogue/bon_detail.html', variables)
```

*urls.py*

```
from django.conf.urls import url
from django.views.generic import DetailView

from catalogue import views
from catalogue.models import Bancnote

urlpatterns = [
    url(r'^$', views.index, name='index'),
    url(r'^(?P<pk>\d+)$', DetailView.as_view(model=Bancnote, template_name='catalogue/bon_detail.html'))
]
```

*index.html*

```
{% extends 'catalogue/base.html' %}
{% block title %}Catalogue{% endblock %}

{% include  'catalogue/includes/header.html'%}

{% block content %}
    {% if bons %}
        <div class="container-fluid infinite-container">
            <div class="row infinite-item">
                {% for bon in bons %}
                    {% if forloop.counter0|divisibleby:"4" %}
            </div>
                        <div class="row infinite-item">
                    {% endif %}
                    <div class="col-sm-3 col-lg-3">
                        <div style="display: block; text-align: center; margin: 0 auto">
                            <a href="{{ bon.id }}">
                                <img src="{{ bon.image.url }}" style="width: 50%; height: 50%"/>
                                <h5>{{ bon.par }} {{ bon.type }} {{ bon.year_from}}-{{ bon.year_to }}</h5>
                            </a>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                {% endfor %}
                        </div>
        </div>

        {% if bons.has_next %}
            <a class="infinite-more-link" href="?page={{ bons.next_page_number }}">More</a>
        {% endif %}

        <div class="loading" style="display: none;">
            Loading...
        </div>

        {% if bons.has_other_pages %}
            <div style="position:fixed; left: 50%; top: 93%;">
                <ul class="pagination" id="pag">
                {% if bons.has_previous %}
                    <li><a href="?page={{ bons.previous_page_number }}">&laquo;</a></li>
                {% else %}
                    <li class="disabled"><span>&laquo;</span></li>
                {% endif %}
                {% for i in bons.paginator.page_range %}
                    {% if bons.number == i %}
                        <li class="active"><span>{{ i }} <span class="sr-only">(current)</span></span></li>
                    {% else %}
                        <li><a href="?page={{ i }}">{{ i }}</a></li>
                    {% endif %}
                {% endfor %}
                {% if bons.has_next %}
                    <li><a href="?page={{ bons.next_page_number }}">&raquo;</a></li>
                {% else %}
                    <li class="disabled"><span>&raquo;</span></li>
                {% endif %}
                </ul>
            </div>
        {% endif %}

        <script>
            var infinite = new Waypoint.Infinite({
                element: $('.infinite-container')[0],
                onBeforePageLoad: function () {
                    $('.loading').show();
                },
                onAfterPageLoad: function ($items) {
                    $('.loading').hide();
                }
            });
        </script>

    {% endif %}
{% endblock %}

{% include 'catalogue/includes/footer.html' %}
```

*What I have now*
[image]

*Choosing exact page at pagination menu opens separate page*
[image]